# import series of meshes

Tags: animation, mesh, import

I have a series of meshes (created elsewhere) that represent a surface deforming over time, each mesh representing a particular point in time (in .ply format).
Can I import these numerous meshes into Blender to render an animation of the deformation?

All meshes have the same number of vertices and faces -so its kind of like a cloth animation

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can do that just import them in order and join them as shape keys

Comment: If you can export in `.mdd` or `.pc2` you could use the mesh cache modifier.

Comment: Thanks. Cherbhou, With several hundred meshes representing the mesh evolution, I will need to automate this process (does a python script exist already? - I see that MeshFoot is no longer available. sambler - no pc2/mdd export option from the mesh creation software. it comes as NetCDF file. I will look at the pc2/mdd file format to see if I can write a translator

Comment: SOLVED - I managed to work out how to build a pc2 file, and use the point cache modifier. thanks for your direction

Comment: You might also try the Blender add-on [Stop Motion OBJ](https://github.com/neverhood311/Stop-motion-OBJ). It supports sequences of .PLY, .OBJ, and .STL files. It also supports geometry with different vertex counts from frame to frame.