# Import sequence of PLY meshes

Tags: mesh, import

I am trying to import a sequence of PLY meshes, but I could not find any full explanation on how to do it. [This questions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27107/import-series-of-meshes) seems to have tackled the same problem, but the answer is not too detailed so I cannot reproduce it. Could somebody provide me with the full details on how to do it please?

Comment: You might also try the Blender add-on [Stop Motion OBJ](https://github.com/neverhood311/Stop-motion-OBJ). It supports sequences of .PLY, .OBJ, and .STL files. It also supports geometry with different vertex counts from frame to frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This script](https://gist.github.com/brio1009/0f6a81df3408d29f9c4e) turned out to be exactly what I was looking for. It basically loads and renders one PLY at the time, therefore you can even use a per-frame texture. Downside is that you can not previsualize the meshes as you browse through the timeline, but it did the job for me.

Answer (score 3):

Blender supports only a handful of mesh formats as sequences, `.mdd`, `.pc2`, and in [test builds](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?399763-Dev-Custom-Builds-Alembic-I-O&p=3055046#post3055046), alembic (`.abc`). This is done using the "mesh cache" modifier. If you have an external tool that can convert/re-export the sequence to one of these formats, that's your best bet.